# Comportamento estranho ao tentar apagar comentário

Tags: suporte, status-intencional

Ao tentar apagar um comentário em uma [publicação bloqueada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/590948/103217), eu recebo uma mensagem de erro não relacionada com a ação. Ação (de apagar um comentário) não surte efeito.

Passos para reproduzir:

- Ir para uma publicação bloqueada
- Apagar um comentário.

Uma mensagem de erro que diz: `Comentários em publicações bloqueadas não podem receber votos`

Mas a minha ação foi a de excluir um comentário.
A ação de excluir um comentário não é concluída.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É o comportamento esperado.

A publicação em questão está justamente com comentários bloqueados (vide quadro de aviso), o que implica em nenhuma alteração sem uma intervenção administrativa.

Por sua vez, o link de remoção é um 'voto de remoção', inclusive pode vir de qualquer usuário. O que muda é que o voto do autor do comentário é soberano, então ele sozinho é suficiente quando não há bloqueio.

Se quiser remover num caso desse tipo de bloqueio, basta sinalizar para moderação. Normalmente os comentários são removidos quando é duplicação (justamente para não descentralizar informação) mas preservei o seu temporariamente para não desmerecer seu esforço em orientar quem fez a pergunta - mas independente disso ia acabar removendo depois de um tempo, de qualquer forma, (edit: o que já ocorreu, considerando que já houve uma janela boa de oportunidade para leitura).